# Stuck in a logical problem. How do I loop through a json tree having unknown nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, angular, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have to build a graph kind of thing where I have a output of a json tree. This json tree will have multiple unknown levels of nested arrays. I am not able to iterate through these json arrays as I cannot build a 'for loop'.

How will be my logic here and how will my HTML code be?

I found a handful of duplicate questions which didnt answer properly OR I am still not developed enough to understand them.

This is the JSON Structure I am dealing with:

```
{
  "name": "TEST",
  "children": [
    {
      "title": "a",
      "description": "a",
      "children": [
        {
          "title": "b1",
          "description": "b1",
          "children": [
            {
              "title": "c1",
              "description": "c1",
              "children": [
                {
                  "title": "e1",
                  "description": "e1",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "title": "d2",
              "description": "d2",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title": "b2",
          "description": "b2",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The image shows expected output. Also I am trying to achive this in angular 7.
[image: The image shows expected output]

Comment: Use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57651224/stuck-in-a-logical-problem-how-do-i-loop-through-a-json-tree-having-unknown-nes#comment101752860_57651224)

Comment: can you please explain it with a example

Comment: https://netbasal.com/recursion-in-angular-components-1cd636269b12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do this recursively.

The first thing you need to do is create a custom component where we will display your data in the template recursively. This component will check if there are any `children` present in the current iteration and if there are, it will call itself by passing in the `children` data.

Here is what the template in your recursive component will look like

```html
<ul *ngFor="let detail of details">
    <li>
        <div>
            Title: {{detail.title}}
            <br />
            Description: {{detail.description}}
        </div>
        <test *ngIf="detail.children" [details]="detail.children"></test>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your parent component, you simply call your recursive component passing in the initial data (which for you is `data.children` where `data` is the sample JSON in the OP).

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-recursion-in-components).

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursive function for this.

**HTML**

```
<div #parent></div>
```

**TypeScript**

I suggest two approaches to achieve this. you can use one of those.

**1. Use for loop inside recursive function.**

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {

    myObj = {...};
    @ViewChild('parent') d1:ElementRef;
    constructor() {}

    createArrayUsingFor() {
      let recursiveFn = (obj) => {

        for (let i = 0 ; i < obj.children.length; i++) {

          const html = `<div><p>${obj.children[i].title}</p><p>${obj.children[i].description}</p></div>`
          this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

          if (obj.children[i].children.length > 0) {

            recursiveFn(obj.children[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      recursiveFn(this.myObj);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.createArrayUsingFor();
    }
}
```

**2. Use map function inside recursive function.**

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent  {

    myObj = {...};
    @ViewChild('parent') d1:ElementRef;
    constructor() {}

    createArrayUsingMap() {
      let recursiveFn = (obj) => {

        if (obj.title && obj.description) {
          const html = `<div><p>${obj.title}</p><p>${obj.description}</p></div>`
          this.d1.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
        }

        obj.children.map(recursiveFn)
      }
      recursiveFn(this.myObj);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.createArrayUsingMap();
    }
}
```

**Find Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57651224?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Here.**

**Note:** If you need nice html structure like the image in your question, you need to define a **level** for each object in your array(to each child of each children) and you need set styles according to that level. As an example set `margin-left` for each `div` according to that **level**.